# conda install commercial package

Tags: python, conda, cplex

I am trying to install some tool which requires cplex. Recommended way of installing this tool is via the use of conda. I installed full version of cplex (academic licence) from source code and then also run python setup.py install which was available inside cplex installation. When I try `import cplex` from within python console it works well without returning any error. Furthermore,

```
conda list | egrep "cplex"
```

returns

```
cplex                     12.8.0.0                  <pip>
```

However, when typing

```
conda search cplex
```

I am getting the following error:

```
  PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

      cplex

Current channels: 
(here it lists some channel names)
```

Is there a way to resolve this (looks like channels are not aware of cplex and it should be added to some of them).

Please note that the problems I am trying to solve have a lot of variables so free version of cplex which seems to be easier to install was not an option and any advice recommending the use of free cplex version unfortunately wouldn't be of any help in my case.

Comment: The fact that it appears when you do `conda list` means you have the package installed already, from pip it seems (see [Cplex PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/cplex/)). Cplex is not in the default Anaconda package channel, though, but there seems to be a version in the IBMDecisionOptimization channel (see [package page](https://anaconda.org/IBMDecisionOptimization/cplex)), you'll see it with `conda search -c ibmdecisionoptimization cplex`. I don't know whether these are the versions that you need or not, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. In the meantime I actually managed to resolve the issue by first installing cplex using conda-build and  conda recipe from https://bitbucket.org/dranew/conda_recipes/src. After that I run "conda install --use-local cplex" and finally run "conda config --add channels local" and cplex then was among the available channels.